# Unused variable in FILE structure

Tags: c, file, struct, io, stream

I was looking at `struct _IO_FILE`:

```
struct _IO_FILE
{
  int _flags;       /* High-order word is _IO_MAGIC; rest is flags. */

  /* The following pointers correspond to the C++ streambuf protocol. */
  char *_IO_read_ptr;   /* Current read pointer */
  char *_IO_read_end;   /* End of get area. */
  char *_IO_read_base;  /* Start of putback+get area. */
  char *_IO_write_base; /* Start of put area. */
  char *_IO_write_ptr;  /* Current put pointer. */
  char *_IO_write_end;  /* End of put area. */
  char *_IO_buf_base;   /* Start of reserve area. */
  char *_IO_buf_end;    /* End of reserve area. */

  ...

  void *_freeres_buf;
  size_t __pad5;
  int _mode;
  /* Make sure we don't get into trouble again.  */
  char _unused2[15 * sizeof (int) - 4 * sizeof (void *) - sizeof (size_t)];
};
```

and I noticed this variable `char _unused2[15 * sizeof (int) - 4 * sizeof (void *) - sizeof (size_t)];`

what is the point of this variable? and what about that comment "Make sure we don't get into trouble again."?

Comment: If you look at the corresponding implementation of the functions using this structure (presumably `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite` etc.) you might get more information. Without seeing these implementations nobody can tell what this is used for. Where exactly did you find this struct and on which platform?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I dowloaded the library and used VScode to find any reference, but I didn't get any result, so I suppose that is used for padding, but why? aren't all the struct allineated 'automatically'?

Comment: I just searched my entire C drive for files containing `struct _IO_FILE` - and failed to find one! I have a number of different C and C++ compilers installed: MSVC, clang-cl, Borland, Digital Mars (I think), Orange-C (maybe). What platform/compiler are you using?

Comment: @malloc which library did you download from where???

Comment: @AdrianMole the file is in /glibc/libio/bits/types/struct_FILE.h (https://github.com/lattera/glibc). I don't think that it varies very much from each version(for the one >2.x)

Comment: @AdrianMole https://github.com/lattera/glibc

Comment: @r3mainer *If you want to write portable code that won't suddenly break, then you should really just treat it as an opaque data structure*  There's no "should" about it.  If you want to write portable code, then you **must** treat `FILE` as an opaque structure because on many implementations it **is** an opaque structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an old one.  This field was first added with commit 1ea89a402d892b68b193e2e4390d8eb33ed686e7 on October 13, 1997 by one of the RedHat developers.  It originally was in the file libio/libioP.h.  The following code was added at that time:

```
/* We had to extend _IO_FILE but this isn't easily possible without
   compatibility problems.  So we mimic the C++ way to do this which
   especially takes care that the position of the vtable stays the
   same.  */
struct _IO_FILE_complete
{
  struct _IO_FILE_plus plus;
  _IO_off64_t _offset;
  int _unused2[16]; /* Make sure we don't get into trouble again.  */
};
```

So it looks like this field was originally added to handle C++ compatibility regarding the vtable.

Over time, the size and type of this field was modified as more fields were added to this struct to keep the same offset.  The current version of this struct contains one additional `int` field, one additional `size_t` field, and four additional pointer fields, which accounts for the size difference between the original and current version.